# installing an app with administrative privilege in android

Tags: android

We can install an app with administrative privilege in android. This is very much possible. When the app is installed an activity appears showing up "If we want to activate the administrative privilege?"

But my doubt here is, I want the app to be installed with administrative privileges without user explicitly clicking on Activate(which appears when app is installed).

Actually in my app, there is no activity and the main class is extending application. With in the onCreate() of it, I gave necessary code for installing it as administrative privilege app. The app is getting installed and its even getting listed in the

select device administrators (Settings->Location & Security-> Select device administrators)

But, it is not checked by default after the install. Can I check that by default during the install.

Hope I was clear enough. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Probably no. Like you can't set a softkeyboard as default during installation for security reasons. "without user explicitly clicking on Activate" definately not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I check that by default during the install.

No, sorry.

> I want the app to be installed with administrative privileges without user explicitly clicking on Activate(which appears when app is installed).

That would be a massive security hole.